# Unable to play reels using magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I want to play any videos which is on youtube with using magnific-popup but it is not working

getting this error with reels

[image]

This is my JS code

```
$('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
                disableOn: 700,
                type: 'iframe',
                mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
                removalDelay: 160,
                preloader: false,
                fixedContentPos: false
            });
```

And this is my dummy video that I wanted to play:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9kXstb9FF4

Comment: Any more clues in the browser's console, or network tool?

Comment: Console showing this error : Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.

Comment: In network section these api's were calling internally: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id?slf_rd=1
https://jnn-pa.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.waa.v1.Waa/Create
https://jnn-pa.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.waa.v1.Waa/GenerateIT
https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8

Comment: Please help me to solve it